# Css files would not transfer using nodeJS express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send the files of a whole project with nodeJS express, but only the html files seem to get transferred. Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/home.html");
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
```

This is the nodeJS file, which is inside the Folder of the project. Everything else (html files, css files, js files) is inside the folder 'public' which is a subfolder inside the folder of the project.

Comment: css have absolutley nothiong to do with your backend

Comment: @Ifaruki Could you please be more specific? What should I look into then?

Comment: into your `home.html`, how do you import your css there

Comment: @Ifaruki I have solved the css problem, the JS file still does not work. Is it again not related to the backend? Here is the html code which links the stylesheet and the js to the html:
```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: what error appear?